# addEventListener without preventDefault in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I just started learning phonegap.

I have this code :

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){ app.onBackButton(e); }, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        splash.initialize();
    },

    onBackButton: function(e) {

    },

};
```

`onBackButton` is an empty function (no `e.preventDefault();`), but when I try in android the back button default behavior is not triggered (it should be close the app).

I want to be able to easily change the back button behavior by modifying`onBackButton` function.

my question is How to add event listener to back button without preventing its default behavior?

Comment: You mean you want to close the app on backbutton?

Comment: yes, after calling `onBackButton`

Comment: What about @user3110424's answer. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have `overrided` the `dafault` behaviour of back button. And you are doing nothing in it so it is not doing as you expect. If you override the behavior of the back button then you have to manually do it. Otherwise dont set the `eventlistener` on backbutton.

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

putting the above line in your function for back button will exit the `App` whenever you will press the `back button`.